# How to fill App Store Privacy Questioner if I am using Facebook SDK for app install only?

Tags: ios, facebook

Can anyone who use Facebook SDK only to check app installs with Facebook/Instagram apps point me to direction of how to fill Apple Appstore Privacy Questioner? There is little info on what exactly Facebook collects in that case, they have a blog post but it is not clear for me from this one:
[Preparing for Apple’s App Store Data Disclosure Requirements](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2020/10/22/preparing-for-apple-app-store-data-disclosure-requirements/)

It looks from what I was able to find that if you use SDK only to check for app installs then this SDK use SKAdNetwork which is anonymous and should not be tracked as well? Also if that is the case should I set FacebookAutoLogAppEventsEnabled to false will it still count app installs?

If somebody have exact setup please point me to the right place thanks!